# Problem with insert value in database with json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, json

I want insert on a row of database table, following value with following php code(`foreach`) but after insert get following error, what do i do?

**Values:**

```
<div class="column">
    <input type="text" name="start_date[1][]" value="1111">
    <input type="text" name="end_date[1][]" value="1111">
    <input type="text" name="price_change[1][]" value="1111">
</div>
<div class="column">
    <input type="text" name="start_date[2][]" value="2222">
    <input type="text" name="end_date[2][]" value="2222">
    <input type="text" name="price_change[2][]" value="2222">
</div>
<div class="column">
    <input type="text" name="start_date[3][]" value="3333">
    <input type="text" name="end_date[3][]" value="3333">
    <input type="text" name="price_change[3][]" value="3333">
</div>
```

**Php code:**

```
    $residence_ups_input = $this->input->post('start_date');
    $residence_upe_input = $this->input->post('end_date');
    $residence_upc_input = $this->input->post('price_change');
    var_dump($residence_ups_input); // output this is: nobool(false)
    $residence_p = array();
    foreach ($residence_ups_input as $idx => $name) { //line 134        
        $residence_p[] = array(
            'start_date' => $residence_ups_input[$idx],
            'end_date' => $residence_upe_input[$idx],
            'price_change' => $residence_upc_input[$idx]
        );
    }
    ;
    $data = array(
        //'name' => $this -> input -> post('name'),
        'residence_p' => json_encode($residence_p)
    );
    $this->db->insert('tour_foreign', $data);
```

**Error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Warning
>  Message: Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach()
>  Filename: inser.php
>  Line
>   Number: 134

Comment: Please see my **values** in above cod, they are array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all columns:

```
<div class="column">
    <input type="text" name="start_date[1][]" value="1111">
    <input type="text" name="end_date[1][]" value="1111">
    <input type="text" name="price_change[1][]" value="1111">
</div>
....
```

to:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="column">
    <input type="text" name="start_date[]" value="1111">
    <input type="text" name="end_date[]" value="1111">
    <input type="text" name="price_change[]" value="1111">
</div>
....

</form>
```

Comment: there is something wrong in your code because I've tested and it works, haves you the `<form method="post">` tag?? see the update

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 foreach ($residence_ups_input as $idx => $name) {
```

with

```
 foreach (get_object_vars($residence_ups_input) as $idx => $name) {
```

you are passing an object to foreach, it wants an associative array. From now on do

```
json_decode($string, true)
```

instead of

```
json_decode($string)
```

and access the variable like this:

```
$var['key'];
```

instead of
    $var->key

Comment: I do not in code `json_decode($string)` , i use of `codeigniter`. it is true

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not familiar with `codeigniter`, what is that?

Answer (score 0):

the `$residence_ups_input`  variable is not an array

use this code :

```
array_push($residence_ups_input,$this->input->post('start_date'));
array_push($residence_upe_input,$this->input->post('end_date'));
array_push($residence_upc_input,$this->input->post('price_change'));
```

to get the values then use the `foreach()`

Comment: $residence_ups_input is an array containing price_change only